# Microsoft FileSink Mpeg4

Tags: mp4, ms-media-foundation, encoder, mpeg-dash, muxer

I have 2 questions

1)How do I write raw data to a file sinker. I am trying to mux. 
2)How do I make sure the sinked data is not written to a file but to a memory buffer

So in Detail:

I am trying to use windows MPEG-4 File Sink to write some Intel SDK Encoded  avc or hevc to memory and send it to websocket.

what is the right approach?

Can I just feed raw hevc or avc as (byte*, length) to MPEG-4 File Sink? 
Or Do I need to wrap the Intel Encoder into a Custom Windows Media Foundation Encoder(well I can just use GUID to get the Intel Encoder anyway) from Windows Media Frame work. Correct me If I am wrong please.

So I have 2 problems, How do I write my raw data(avc||hevc) to MP4 Sinker(Encoded by a 3rd Party Encoder)

Do I need to implement a custom Sinker , And how custom is it. Can I inherit part of the MPEG4 Sinker(After all I do not want to re implement a full container for Mp4)

Or Modify MPEG4 Sinker behavior so that it does not write it to a file but writes to a Memory

I know I feel like I re iterated myself A few times. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you wrap the encoded bitstream in an [IMFSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfsample) you can just call [IMFStreamSink::ProcessSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfstreamsink-processsample). To wrap it in the `IMFSample`, create a memory buffer `IMFMediaBuffer` with [MFCreateMemoryBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatememorybuffer) , then create an `IMFSample` with [MFCreateSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatesample) and add the buffer to it with [IMFSample::AddBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nf-mfobjects-imfsample-addbuffer). And then pass it to the stream sink. Also, if you can constrain the output bitstream length you can actually use the underlying memofy from `IMFMediaBuffer` by using [IMFMediaBuffer::Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nf-mfobjects-imfmediabuffer-lock) to obtain the pointer to the underlying memory and passing that to the Intel SDK.

2) When creating the MPEG-4 sink via [MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatempeg4mediasink%C2%B0) you pass in an [IMFByteStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfbytestream) instance. You can make your own class which implements this interface and writes the data directly to memory or wherever you need. If you do not want to do a full implementation there are also [MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemfbytestreamonstream) and [MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemfbytestreamonstreamex) which can wrap an [IStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) instance into a `IMFByteStream` but I have never used those and I am not aware of the underlying memory semantics. You can create a memory backed `IStream` with [SHCreateMemStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream) and [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-createstreamonhglobal).

I have used Intel SDK quite long ago but if I remember it had a MFT compatible encoder, but I always used the plain C++ one, and thus I am not sure how they differ in terms of configuration etc. But if the MFT one works, then you can setup a proper pipeline without processing the bitstream samples yourself as stated in (1) and just handle (2).

Also, performance wise, since as far as I remember Intel SDK did work on Direct3D surfaces as well, you could look into [MFCreateDXSurfaceBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatedxsurfacebuffer) to used Direct3D surfaces instead of memory buffers for wrapping the data.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. This was all I needed. Last time I used MS stuff was DirectShow which is 1000 years old. 
So thanks.